# How to use the trader_macd function in PHP with values from bittrex API?

Tags: php

I need to create a script in PHP wherein I take values from the Bittrex API and return the MACD representation of a specific currency. I´d also like to know when the MACD line and Signal line crossover each other.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a pecl php library that can do that: `trader`. http://php.net/manual/en/book.trader.php To install: sudo pecl install trader